# non homogeneous recurrence relations

Tags: recurrence-relations

how to solve the particular equation of this problem
Im not able to equate the polynomial formed 
I have taken $a_n(p) = A_0+A_1n+A_2 n^22^n$
is it right ?
$a_n-4 a_{n-1} + 4a_{n-2} = 3n + 2^n$ ?

Comment: You have found the general solution $a_n=(B+Cn)2^n$ by the usual method of solving the auxillary equation ?
Your particular solution is spot on ... I will supply the details on request ?

Comment: yes i have found the general solution please provide the details

Answer (score 0):

So we have found the general solution $a_n=(B+Cn)2^n$ which satisfies $a_{n}-4a_{n-1}+4a_{n-2}=0$.
We now need to deal with $3n+ \color{red}{0}$ and $2^n$ ... $a_n=A_0 +A_1 n $ will deal with the first term. The second term is slightly trickier ... we would try $2^n$ but we already know that this will give zero, similarly $n2^n$ will give zero, so try $ A_{2} n^2 2^n$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
 a_{n}-4a_{n-1}+4a_{n-2} &=&A_0+A_1 n-4( A_0+A_1 (n-1)) +4(A_0+A_1 (n-2))\\&=A&_{1}n+(A_0-4A_1) =3n+ \color{red}{0} \\
 A_1=3 \\
 A_0-4 A_1=0
\end{eqnarray*}
So $A_0=12$ ... now the $2^n$ term ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
 a_{n}-4a_{n-1}+4a_{n-2} = A_{2} n^2 2^n-4A_{2} (n-1)^2 2^{n-1}+4A_{2} (n-2)n^2 2^{(n-2)}=2^2 A\\=A_2 2^{n} (n^2-2(n-1)^2+(n-2)^2)=A_2 2^{n} (n^2-2n^2+4n-2+n^2-4n+4) = 2 A_2 2^{n} =2^{n}
\end{eqnarray*}
So $A_2=\frac{1}{2}$.